Removing users/groups from fileshare ACL with Powershell (Not Responding)
I have a PowerShell script designed to update Access Control Lists (ACLs) for a large directory structure based on a CSV input file. The script works fine for a small number of folders and files but freezes when it needs to process a large root folder containing millions of subfolders and files.
Below you will find a small part of the Powershell script I am using:
function RemoveGroupsH {
    param (
        [string]$csvdataPath
    )

    $batchSize = 1000  #Tried different batch sizes, e.g., 10, 500, 1000

    try {
        $csvFileNameWithoutExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($csvdataPath)
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
        $outputFileName = "${csvFileNameWithoutExtension}_${timestamp}.txt"
        $outputFilePath = "D:\Scripts\Logs\RemoveGroupsH\$outputFileName"

        $csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvdataPath
        $csvData = @($csvData) # Ensure $csvData is an array

        $foldersProcessed = 0
        $folders = @()

        foreach ($record in $csvData) {
            $migrateFromPath = $record.'Migrate From'
            $groupNameToRetain = "XXXX\FilesharegroupX"

            # Add root folder to the batch
            $folders += [PSCustomObject]@{ Path = $migrateFromPath; IsRoot = $true }

            # Get all subfolders
            $subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $migrateFromPath -Directory -Recurse
            foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) {
                $folders += [PSCustomObject]@{ Path = $subfolder.FullName; IsRoot = $false }
            }

            # Process folders in batches
            while ($folders.Count -gt 0) {
                $currentBatch = $folders[0..([Math]::Min($batchSize, $folders.Count) - 1)]
                $folders = $folders[$currentBatch.Count..($folders.Count - 1)]

                foreach ($folder in $currentBatch) {
                    try {
                        $acl = Get-Acl -Path $folder.Path
                        if ($folder.IsRoot) {
                            $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)
                            Set-Acl -Path $folder.Path -AclObject $acl
                        }
                        $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference.Value -ne $groupNameToRetain } | ForEach-Object {
                            $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)
                        }
                        $acl.AddAccessRule($rule1)

                        try {
                            Set-Acl -Path $folder.Path -AclObject $acl -ErrorAction Stop
                            Add-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value "Removed unwanted groups and added users to $($folder.Path)"
                            Add-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value "------------------------------------"
                        } catch {
                            Add-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value "Error processing path: $($folder.Path)"
                            Add-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value $_.Exception.Message
                            Add-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value "------------------------------------"
                        }
                    } catch {
                        Add-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value "Error processing path: $($folder.Path)"
                        Add-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value $_.Exception.Message
                        Add-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value "------------------------------------"
                    }
                }

                $foldersProcessed += $currentBatch.Count
                Write-Host "Processed $foldersProcessed folders..."
            }
        }
    } catch {
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
        Add-Content -Path "D:\Scripts\Logs\RemoveGroupsH\Errors_$($timestamp).txt" -Value "Error in RemoveGroupsH function: $_"
        throw $_
    }
}

# Define the access rule outside the loop to avoid recreating it each time
$rule1 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("XXXX\UserXXXX", "Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

Things that I have tried:
- Batch Processing: Implemented batch processing to handle smaller chunks of data.
- Error Handling: Improved error handling to ensure the script skips problematic folders/files and logs errors.
**- Memory Management: **Optimized memory usage by processing and releasing resources promptly.
- Parallel Processing: Considered using parallel processing but concerned about overwhelming system resources.

I have a couple suggestions that may help. First, every Add-Content has to create a file lock on the target file, write to it, and release the lock. Fewer calls is better. Maybe build a batch log and write once per batch. $BatchLog = ForEach($Folder in $currentBatch){<code>}; $BatchLog | Add-Content $outputFilePath. Next, skip inherited Access Rules, and local accounts. Something like $folder.Access | Where{ $_.IdentityReference -notmatch 'builtin|nt authority' -and !$_.IsInherited -and $_.IdentityReference -ne $GroupNameToRetain }

@TheMadTechnician Thank you for your help. The thing is, I need to remove all access for the user, including subfolders and files. If I skip inherited rules as you suggest, it will not remove access for all users at, for example, folder level 3 and files. Am I correct in this?

inherited access is access set at a higher level. So an ACL on C:\Temp\Drivers that is inherited came from either C:\Temp or C:. In order to stop that you have to turn off inheritance for C:\Temp\Drivers entirely, which is usually not the intent of things. Propagation is what applies ACLs on C:\Temp\Drivers to an object or subfolder like C:\Temp\Drivers\Intel.
